# Determine the line of code that causes a segmentation fault? (C lag)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, debian, scheduling

```
int Home(struct linkedList process[], int quantumTime, FILE *fp, FILE *fr, char *ovalue)
{
    char line[LINE_MAX];
    char s1[] = "1)";
    char s2[] = "2)";
    char s3[] = "3)";
    char s4[] = "4)";
    char s5[] = "5)";
    char MenuName[] = "**************CPU Scheduler Simulator**************\n";
    char MenuOne[] = "Scheduling Method   \n";
    char MenuTwo[] = "Preemptive Mode \n";
    char MenuThree[] = "Non-preemptive Mode \n";
    char MenuFour[] = "Show Result \n";
    char MenuFive[] = "End Program \n";
    char Option[] = "Option >";
    int optionNumber;
    strcat(s1, MenuOne);
    printf("%s", MenuName);
    printf("%s", s1);
    strcat(s2, MenuTwo);
    printf("%s", s2);
    strcat(s3, MenuThree);
    printf("%s", s3);
    strcat(s4, MenuFour);
    printf("%s", s4);
    strcat(s5, MenuFive);
    printf("%s", s5);
    printf("%s", Option);
    optionNumber = 0;
    scanf("%d", &optionNumber);
    //printf("buradiyim");
    while (optionNumber != 1 && optionNumber != 2 && optionNumber != 3 && optionNumber != 4 && optionNumber != 5) {
        scanf("%d", &optionNumber);
        //printf("buradiyim");
    }
    switch (optionNumber) {
      case 1:
        system("clear");
        SchedulingMethod(MenuOne, process, quantumTime, fp, fr, ovalue);
        break;
      case 2:
        system("clear");
        printf("Preemptive Mode Active\n");
        mode = 1;
        //printf("%d",mode);
        Home(process, quantumTime, fp,fr,ovalue);
        break;
      case 3:
        system("clear");
        printf("Non-Preemptive Mode Active\n");
        mode = 0;
        Home(process, quantumTime, fp, fr, ovalue);
        break;
      case 4:
        system("clear");
        fr = fopen(ovalue, "r");
        while (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fr)) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        fclose(fr);
        break;
      case 5:
        system("clear");
        printf("Good Bye\n");
        exit(0);
      default:
        printf("Wrong choice");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Segmentation fault Error.
Option One opens scheduling methods, and after running method 2 methods from there, the Fourth option gives the Segmentation fault Error that you selected. So only one method prints the result, but all the methods that are done need to suppress the results. I also work on my application Debian linux.

Comment: Your debugger will tell you where exactly the segfault occurs.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/LsOyX8nB9Np4WQ

Comment: The first error writes output the .txt method and show result prints it. The other error is Segmentation fault Error after running the 3-4 methods.

Comment: Can I throw out the whole code specifically?

Comment: No, you can't post all your code. We can't help you with this. Learn to use your debugger. Learning the basics will not be long and it will save you a lot of time for resolving this bug as well as other bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`s1` to `s5` only have elements to store their initial contents, so the `strcat()` is causing out-of-range writes. Specify number of elements explicitly to allocate enough elements.

```
    char s1[128] = "1)";
    char s2[128] = "2)";
    char s3[128] = "3)";
    char s4[128] = "4)";
    char s5[128] = "5)";
```

Comment: I did as you said, but the mistake continues. My problem is to read and print the results of .txt from output screen but shows the result of the most recent operation and prints Segmentation fault Error @MikeCAT